# Powershell Call Base Class Function From Overidden Function

Tags: powershell, oop, overriding, base-class

I want to make a call to the parent function from its overidden function, i isolated my problem in the following code:

```
class SomeClass{
  [type]GetType(){
    write-host 'hooked'
    return $BaseClass.GetType() # how do i call the BaseClass GetType function??
  }
}
SomeClass::new().GetType()
```

i am expecting an output like this:

```
hooked
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     SomeClass                                System.Object
```

Comment: `Object.GetType()` is non-virtual and _cannot be overridden_ (although you can hide it in various ways). What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In oder to **call a method on the *base* class**, ***cast* `$this` to it** (`([object] $this).GetType()`, in your case, given that your [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes) *implicitly* derives from `[object]`([`System.Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Object))):

```bash
class SomeClass  {
  [type]GetType(){
    Write-Verbose -Verbose hooked!
    # Casting to [object] calls the original .GetType() method.
    return ([object] $this).GetType()
  }
}

[SomeClass]::new().GetType()
```

As an aside re **referring to the base class in PowerShell [custom classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes)**:

- PowerShell **only allows you to reference the base class via the abstract `base` identifier in base-class *constructor calls***:

  ```bash
  class Foo { [int] $Num; Foo([int] $Num) { $this.Num = $Num } }
  class FooSub : Foo { FooSub() : base(42) { } } # Note the `: base(...)` part
  [FooSub]::new().Num # -> 42
  ```
- **In *methods***, the only (non-reflection-based) way to **refer to the base class** is **via a *type literal*** (cast), which in essence **requires you to *hard-code* the base-class name** (as also shown with `([object] $this)` above):

  ```bash
  class Foo { [string] Method() { return 'hi' } }
  # Note the need to name the base class explicitly, as [Foo].
  class FooSub : Foo { [string] Method() { return ([Foo] $this).Method() + '!' } }
  [FooSub]::new().Method() # -> 'hi!'
  ```

  - **Caveat**: There appears to be a **bug in *Windows PowerShell*** (no longer present in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)), where calling a base class' method fails **if the base class is a  *generic* type that is *constructed with type argument `[pscustomobject]` aka `[psobject]`***. Use a *reflection-based workaround* in that case; e.g.:

    ```bash
    class Foo : System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[pscustomobject] {
      [void] Add([pscustomobject] $item) {
        Write-Verbose -Verbose hooked!
        # Use reflection to call the base class' .Add() method.
        # Note: In *PowerShell Core*, this workaround isn't necessary, and the usual would work:
        #         ([System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[pscustomobject]] $this).Add($item)
        # Note the use of .GetMethod() and .Invoke()
        [System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[pscustomobject]].GetMethod('Add').Invoke($this, [object[]] $item)
      }
    }
    ```

Comment: Would it be worthwhile to add in the GetMethod of the base type from your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74971370/6076137)?